# C# Windows Forms - Scrollbar on Richtextbox does not show up for a second time

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a RichTextBoxElement on my form. When I start my application the element looks like this:

[image]

After that, I drag the window bigger, that the vertical scrollbar leaves. Picture:

[image]

So when I drag the window smaller again, the scrollbar should come back and appear, but it does not. Picture:

[image]

Maybe it is helpful to see my properties for this element:

[image]

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

I am able to reproduce the issue.

Seems like a bug to me. Notice: if you increase the height of window scrollbar will appears properly, but not when you **decrease** it.

[image]

You can use workaround:

```
void richTextBox1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) => richTextBox1.Refresh();
```