# Windows Form: How can I reset the scrollbar to top in RichTextBox when I switch less text contents?

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

When RichTextBox has long text and the scrollbar also shows, I click the down arrow of the scrollbar to make it scroll to the bottom.

[image: demo]

Then, I click **Short Text** to make RichTextBox fill less text(In theory, in this case, the scroll bar should be automatically hidden), we can notice that RichTextbox's content has been updated, but the scrollbar still shows and is at the bottom. If we select a few lines of text, we can notice the part of the scrollbar disappears. This is indeed a weird bug(Schrödinger's scrollbar)

It seems to be an issue of WinForm.
So, I have to think of workaround to bypass it.
Then, I add these codes and expect to reset the scrollbar to top, but still does not work.
Besides, I also use windows messages([EM_SHOWSCROLLBAR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-showscrollbar)) to hide the scrollbar, but still does not work.

Now, I have no idea, could you please give me advice?

```
private void ShortTextButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            richTextBox.Rtf = @"{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\nouicompat\deflang3081{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}}
{\*\generator Riched20 10.0.22621}\viewkind4\uc1 
\pard\f0\fs20 Test Line21\par
\par
Test Line22\par
\par
Test Line23\par
\par
Test Line23\par
}";
            richTextBox.SelectionStart = 0;
            richTextBox.ScrollToCaret();
        }
```

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestMouseEventForCitrix
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.richTextBox = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();
            this.ShortTextButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.LongTextButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // richTextBox1
            // 
            this.richTextBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(28, 69);
            this.richTextBox.Name = "richTextBox1";
            this.richTextBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(294, 300);
            this.richTextBox.TabIndex = 2;
            this.richTextBox.Text = "";
            // 
            // button2
            // 
            this.ShortTextButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(185, 33);
            this.ShortTextButton.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(2);
            this.ShortTextButton.Name = "button2";
            this.ShortTextButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(137, 27);
            this.ShortTextButton.TabIndex = 5;
            this.ShortTextButton.Text = "Short Text";
            this.ShortTextButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.ShortTextButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.ShortTextButton_Click);
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.LongTextButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(28, 30);
            this.LongTextButton.Name = "button1";
            this.LongTextButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(137, 33);
            this.LongTextButton.TabIndex = 6;
            this.LongTextButton.Text = "Long Text";
            this.LongTextButton.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.LongTextButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.LongTextButton_Click);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(343, 392);
            this.Controls.Add(this.LongTextButton);
            this.Controls.Add(this.ShortTextButton);
            this.Controls.Add(this.richTextBox);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        private System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox richTextBox;
        private Button ShortTextButton;
        private Button LongTextButton;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void ShortTextButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            richTextBox.Rtf = @"{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\nouicompat\deflang3081{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}}
{\*\generator Riched20 10.0.22621}\viewkind4\uc1 
\pard\f0\fs20 Test Line21\par
\par
Test Line22\par
\par
Test Line23\par
\par
Test Line23\par
}";
        }

        private void LongTextButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            richTextBox.Rtf = @"{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\nouicompat\deflang3081{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}}
{\*\generator Riched20 10.0.22621}\viewkind4\uc1 
\pard\f0\fs20 Test Line1\par
\par
Test Line2\par
\par
Test Line3\par
\par
Test Line3\par
\par
Test Line3\par
\par
Test Line3\par
\par
Test Line3\par
\par
Test Line3\par
\par
Test Line3\par
\par
Test Line3\par
\par
Test Line3\par
\par
Test Line3\par
\par
Test Line3\par
\par
Test Line3\par
\par
Test Line3\par
\par
Test Line3\par
}";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Reset the VSCROLL position before you replace the RTF entirely. E.g., `SendMessage(richTextBox.Handle, 0x0115, 4, 0);` (4 = `SB_THUMBPOSITION`)

Answer (score 1):

This "BUG" seems to have been fixed in .NET, but it still exists in the .NET Framework. I tried two versions, v4.5.2 and v4.8, and found that the "BUG" occurs whenever the scrollbar is clicked. So, I tried adding the following code:

```csharp
richTextBox.ScrollBars = RichTextBoxScrollBars.None;
richTextBox.ScrollBars = RichTextBoxScrollBars.Both;
```

It seems to have resolved the issue.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, it can work. But the action of modifying the type of scrollbar will re-create the handle, we can clearly find that RichTextBox control flashed once. I don't think it's a good idea.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  I tried to use WinAPI, both WindowStyle and SCROLLINFO have failed. I tried moving `richTextBox.SelectionStart = 0; richTextBox.ScrollToCaret();` before `richTextBox.Rtf = "......"`, and the BUG no longer appeared. You can give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Other people have also got this problem, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42365398/c-sharp-windows-forms-scrollbar-on-richtextbox-does-not-show-up-for-a-second-t), and they fixed it with this function:

`void richTextBox1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) => richTextBox1.Refresh()`

Refreshing the textbox should work and update the scrollbar to its correct visibility.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but sorry this doesn't work.